# Cannot resolve symbol 'GeoPoint'

Tags: java, android, geopoints

Not sure what's going on but when I try to call GeoPoint to get my devices current longitude and latitude I get the notification "Cannot resolve symbol 'GeoPoint'. Not quite sure what's going wrong

```
private void getLastKnownLocation() {
    Log.d(TAG, "getLastKnownLocation: called.");

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<android.location.Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<android.location.Location> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Location location = task.getResult();
                GeoPoint geoPoint = new GeoPoint(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: latitude: " + geoPoint.getLatitude());
                Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: longitude: " + geoPoint.getLongitude());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by : "I get the notification"? This is on the application or on Android Studio? Are you importing the GeoPoint?

Comment: @BrunoDiegoMartins Sorry not sure how to explain it.. the text is red (error) and when I hover over the text to view the problem it says cannot resolve symbol geopoint. (in android studio)

Comment: Did you try importing GeoPoint ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the LatLng instead of GeoPoint:

```
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
```